# Webpack Multi Entry Common Vendor

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have an application with multi entry points. But all entry points use same 3rd party libraries. I want to have those 3rd party libraries alone in one separate file. When I followed the steps in the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html), it moves my application code also into the 3rd vendor chunk file.

```
entry: {
    index: __dirname + "/entry1.js",
    app: __dirname + "/entry2.js",
    vendor: ["axios", "react-router", "react", "react-dom"]
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "[name]-[hash].js")
]
```

Below is the webpack output

```
Hash: 78d489a6e4aec65292b2  
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 8161ms
                         Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
vendor-78d489a6e4aec65292b2.js     925 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
index-78d489a6e4aec65292b2.js    1.87 kB       1  [emitted]  index
app-78d489a6e4aec65292b2.js    1.41 kB       2  [emitted]  app
index-78d489a6e4aec65292b2.css   83 bytes       1  [emitted]  index
vendor-78d489a6e4aec65292b2.js.map    1.05 MB       0  [emitted]  vendor
index-78d489a6e4aec65292b2.js.map     2.3 kB       1  [emitted]  index
index-78d489a6e4aec65292b2.css.map  107 bytes       1  [emitted]  index
app-78d489a6e4aec65292b2.js.map    1.76 kB       2  [emitted]  app
index.html  370 bytes          [emitted]  
app.html  311 bytes          [emitted]  
[0] multi vendor 64 bytes {0} [built]
+ 258 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
+ 3 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "app.html":
+ 3 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
+ 2 hidden modules
```

Opened this [issue in Github 2191](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2191)

Comment: `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            minChunks: 2
        })` and remove the `vendor` entry at all.

Comment: @zerkms that did not fix. It still created another common.js file with in addition vendor had my application entry code too..

Comment: Need more info. Can you attach webpack console output with `-d` flag?

Comment: @BobSponge I have updated the question with webpack output

Comment: Can confirm bug in CommonsChunkPlugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `minChunks` to `Infinity` seems to fix it. Below is the code. Also you can get a [working example here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/explicit-vendor-chunk).

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        minChunks: Infinity
    })
```